# Populating drop-down lists in ADF Forms in Oracle BPM Jdeveloper 12c

Tags: ajax, jdeveloper, oracle12c, business-process-management, oracle-bpm-suite

We're currently in the middle of the migration of a BPM application from Oracle 10g to 12c. As we know, some of the 10g libraries were dropped in the newer versions. Unfortunately, our application depends largely on those deprecated features.

One particular problem were having now is how to populate drop-down lists from an existing payload in the migrated Human Task. In the 10g version of the project, AJAX was used to retrieve these values from the database. 
Once we auto-generated the jspx(including simple components as textboxes and date fields) from the Human Task, we tried using an approach wherein we tried to create JSF managed beans that retrieve the values from the database, then bind that bean to the dropdown component via Expression Builder. It doesn't seem to work though. We were thinking of using the AJAX jsf tag within the generated jspx, but I saw a thread here that discourages doing that.

Is there an alternative way of implementing this?

Comment: Can you post some generic code you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which type of field are you using? Specific ADF Faces components might require specific structures for managed beans.
I would suggest checking the ADF Faces components demo source code for examples of such beans.
Also if your data for the list is coming from a database - you might find this approach easier: https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/adding_lov_to_non_database

Comment: This is a great help. I tried implementing it using this method; it seems to be working except that I'm getting an error when I click on the button of the Choice List object. The error: "bc4j.xcfg is not found in the classpath" is being shown, pointing to the BPM project. Have you encountered something like this?